# How many symmetric words are in a string?

Tags: string-manipulation, text

Determine how many symmetric words are in a given string.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange. What exactly is your question? Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and familiarize yourself with the kind of questions that attract high-quality answers.

Comment: What have you tried?  What code have you written?  What problems resulted from running it?

Comment: What is a symmetric word, is it a palindrome?

Comment: symmetrical words that are the same read from left to right and from right to left for example "bobhousesam" answer bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringCount["bobhousesam", x:(_~~__)/;PalindromeQ[x], Overlaps -> All]
```

> 2

```
StringCases["bobhousesam", x:(_~~__)/;PalindromeQ[x], Overlaps -> All]
```

> {"bob", "ses"}

**Steps:**

`_~~__` is a string pattern which stands for two-or-more characters (strictly, one character followed by a one-or-more characters. See [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), [`BlankSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) and [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) in the docs.

We can use it to extract substrings with two or more characters:

```
StringCases["bobhousesam", _ ~~ __, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {"bobhousesam", "bobhousesa", "bobhouses", "bobhouse", "bobhous", 
>   "bobhou", "bobho", "bobh", "bob", "bo", "obhousesam", "obhousesa", 
>   "obhouses", "obhouse", "obhous", "obhou", "obho", "obh", "ob",
>   "bhousesam", "bhousesa", "bhouses", "bhouse", "bhous", "bhou", "bho", 
>   "bh", "housesam", "housesa", "houses", "house", "hous", "hou", "ho", 
>   "ousesam", "ousesa", "ouses", "ouse", "ous", "ou", "usesam", "usesa", 
>   "uses", "use", "us", "sesam", "sesa", "ses", "se", "esam", "esa", 
>   "es", "sam", "sa", "am"}

(Try it without the `Overlaps -> All` option to see why we need to add this option.)

`x:(_ ~~ __)`  is a pattern *named* `x` (see [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html)) that stands for two-or-more characters. `StringCases["bobhousesam", x:(_ ~~ __), Overlaps -> All]` yields the same output as above.

We use the names to attach conditions (see [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)) to patterns. The patern with condition `x:(_~~__)/;PalindromeQ[x]` is *a string expression named x with two or more characters such that PalindromeQ[x] yields True*.

```
StringCases["bobhousesam", x : (_ ~~ __) /; PalindromeQ[x], Overlaps -> All]
```

> {"bob", "ses"}

Note that if we had used `x:(__)/;PalindromeQ[x]` we would have had

```
StringCases["bobhousesam", x : (__) /; PalindromeQ[x], Overlaps -> All]
```

> {"bob", "b", "o", "b", "h", "o", "u", "ses", "s", "e", "s", "a", "m"}

Comment: can you please explain this?  `x:(_~~__)/;PalindromeQ[x]`

Comment: just not quite clear

Comment: @Ivan912, `_~~__` is a ` string expression pattern which stands for one character followed by a one-or-more characters (see [Blank](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html), [BlankSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) and [StringExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html); `x:pattern` is a pattern named `x` (see [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html)); ...

Comment: ...  `something/; condition[something]` is  a pattern which matches only if the evaluation of `condition[something]` yields `True` (see  [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html)). Altogether, `x:(_~~__)/;PalindromeQ[x]` is _"a string expression x with two or more characters such that PalindromeQ[x] yields True"_.

Comment: Thank you, can you somehow print out every step of it to see how it all works?

Comment: @Ivan912, please see the update.